# The term for doing what others tell you is impossible

Tags: terminology, psychology

I am looking for a word which describes the act of doing something most people think is impossible or when you want to show to someone that you are capable of doing something maybe like revenge or negative encouragement. I'd be happy to see some words related to psychology too.

Comment: ...doing something like "revenge". What's *impossible* about doing that? Can you write an example sentence where this word would be used? It will make it easier for users to suggest the best solutions.

Comment: answers so far more than 'a word'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about doing something that people don't think is possible (or perhaps they just think it's not at all likely for *you*), then you are [**beating the odds**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/beat%20the%20odds):

> to succeed despite not having a good chance of succeeding · Most new restaurants fail, but this one somehow managed to *beat the odds*.

But if you're talking about doing something they didn't think you had it in you to do, then you are acting [**out of character**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/out%20of%20character):

> not in accord with a person's usual qualities or traits · his rudeness was completely *out of character*

Or, perhaps, if you're doing it only because they have repeatedly said you *couldn't* (or wouldn't) do it, then you are acting [**in spite of**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spite) them:

> in defiance or contempt of : without being prevented by · succeeded *in spite of* their opposition

(This is related to doing something [**out of spite**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/out+of+spite) if, like revenge, the intent is negative.)

Answer (score 2):

**Against the grain** - doing something unique, where everyone else (every grain) is against you

**Thinking outside the square** - quite a rare trait for thinking with a different set of boundaries and limitations.  Based on a classic IQ question you can find with your favourite search engine

Answer (score 0):

To [stick your neck out](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/stick-your-neck-out) means to take a risk.

From *Cambridge Dictionary*:

> I’m really **sticking my neck out** by investing my money in this idea.

*Etymonline*:

> To stick one's neck out "take a risk" is first recorded 1919, American English.